# How to use MPI_Sendrecv in pipelined communication?

Tags: c, mpi

I've been trying to solve the parallel version of a Gaussian Elimination using a pipelined communication approach. My code deadlocked when I used `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`and I tried to switch over to `MPI_Sendrecv_replace`. Here's what I've written:

```
     int pred, succ,k;
        MPI_Status stat;
        pred = (size + (rank -1 ))%size;
        succ = (rank + 1) %size;

        for(k=0;k<matrix_size;++k) 
        {
          if(k%size == rank) {
               MPI_Sendrecv_replace(row_comm, matrix_size+1, MPI_DOUBLE,succ,0,
                                    pred, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
          } else {
                  MPI_Sendrecv_replace(row_comm, matrix_size+1,MPI_DOUBLE,succ,0,
                                        pred, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
                   if(succ != k%size) {
                      MPI_Send(row_comm, matrix_size+1, MPI_DOUBLE,succ,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                      }


                  }
}
```

Here, `size` and `rank` are the total number of processors and rank of a processor in the communication topology. `row_comm` is a vector of size `matrix_size+1`. In pipelined communication, the predecessor sends to successor. If the successor's rank is `size-1` then it rolls over and sends to process with rank `0`. However, am I doing this right?

Comment: What's supposed to be the point of the separate send? Please format your code properly.

Comment: The separate send sends the row comm to the next processor immediately. This is a pipelined communication requirement.

Comment: And with which recieve is that supposed to pair? How does it supposed to be different than the send part of the sundress?

Comment: As per the documentation on sendrecv it can receive from mpi send

Comment: Sure it can, but wity each `MPI_Sendrecv` you already have a matching send. So overall you have more sends than receives.

Comment: So how can one implement a pipelined communication with no deadlocks?

Comment: Gaussian elimination in MPI is usually done by scattering columns among ranks - but the columns stay in with the rank during the iterations ([example](https://github.com/jschueths/MPI-Gaussian-Elimination/blob/master/gaussian.cpp)). From your limited code example, I cannot tell what you actually intend to do. Do you mean pipelining as in data moves through the ranks in a chain? Or a ring? Or are you talking about overlapping communication and computation?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this scheme to avoid deadlocks:
IReceive(prev)
IReceive(succ)
ISend(prev)
ISend(succ)
Waitall( 4 handles )

If all processes are in sync, then MPI could get away with no buffering at all.